# SSRS report column is showing wrong results

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Visual Studio 2017

**Setup:**

Parameter: COMPLEX ,   DataSource: 1

Datasets:  Stored Procedure A,  Stored Procedure B

Parameter picks the Apartment Complex Names from SP A, while SP B provides address info for rest of the report.

**Problem:** I choose the Apartment Complex Names in the PREVIEW, and next I click on View the Report button.  The result is showing wrong apartment complex names in the column  called Complex, the names that I did not choose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your dataset showing the data for the report has the parameters coming from the stored procedure A. Typically if the results are not filtering by a selected parameter the issues is the parameters on the dataset are not setup correctly or are missing.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your kind reply and help.  I checked Parm values per your advise, and they look correct, nothing is missing. I am being told the following: " Please ensure the complex parameter is updated to read correctly when over 20 values have been selected.  Please refer back to the template for how the expression should look."  I think they are asking me to create an expression that will read correctly values over 20.  Any ideas how to do it? I currently  have this expression in reports heading: =join(Parameters!Complex.Label, ",")   Thanks for  your help.